# Incorrect emacs indentation in a C++ class with DLL export specification

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I often write classes with a DLL export/import specification, but this seems to confuse emacs' syntax parser.  I end up with something like:

```
class myDllSpec Foo {
 public:
  Foo( void );
};
```

Notice that the "public:" access spec is indented incorrectly, as well as everything that follows it.

When I ask emacs to describe the syntax at the beginning of the line containing public, I get a return of:

```
((label 352))
```

If I remove the myDllSpec, the indentation is correct, and emacs tells me that the syntax there is:

```
((inclass 352) (access-label 352))
```

Which seems correct and reasonable.  So I conclude that the syntax parser is not able to handle the DLL export spec, and that this is what's causing my indentation trouble.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to teach the parser about my labels.  Seems that this is pretty common practice, so I'm hoping there's a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC#toc13 you can set up a "microsoft" style.

Drop this into your `.emacs`:

```
(c-add-style "microsoft"
             '("stroustrup"
               (c-offsets-alist
                (innamespace . -)
                (inline-open . 0)
                (inher-cont . c-lineup-multi-inher)
                (arglist-cont-nonempty . +)
                (template-args-cont . +))))
(setq c-default-style "microsoft")
```

or leave the default and set it manually via `M-x c-set-style` to `microsoft`.

Your example renders this indentation:

```
class myDllSpec Foo {
public:
    Foo( void );
};
```